# iMacro Help: ATTR ID for checkbox keep changing and asterisks not work

Tags: google-chrome, imacros

As title, I am trying to click the clickbox automatically using Chrome iMacros. However the ATTR id for the checkbox keep changing. I found that replace the id with asterisk * should work, however, I got no luck using the asterisk, so anyone know if there are any other solution? Here is the sample iMacros:

Direct capture using iMacros record:

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX ATTR=ID:gwt-uid-7116 CONTENT=YES

Replace asterisks(*):

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX ATTR=ID:gwt-uid-* CONTENT=YES

Comment: What do you get when you play this line: `TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX ATTR=ID:gwt-uid-* EXTRACT=HTM`?

Comment: @Shugar : using * instead the actual ID, the imacro will keep running without errors, however, the box doesn't check.

Comment: I think you should use [Relative Positioning](http://wiki.imacros.net/Data_Extraction#Extract_with_relative_Positioning) based on some unchangeable element on the web page.